# How to detect a player close to a specific block Minecraft 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am doing a troll to my friend, but I am not very good at commands. I am trying like to replace diamond ore/blocks in a radius of 5 around him with stone. I tried it with `/execute` and `/testfor` but it either didn't work or work but not very well (one had bugs and didn't change the block). I don't have my command because I deleted the world.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, create two repeating command blocks containing the following commands:

Command one:

```
/execute YourFriendsName ~ ~ ~ /fill ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 ~5 ~5 ~5 stone 0 replace diamond_ore
```

Command two:

```
/execute YourFriendsName ~ ~ ~ /fill ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 ~5 ~5 ~5 stone 0 replace diamond_block
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a command block behind it or below it (but make sure it isn't in sight).

In 1.9 and above, you can change it to a repeating command block (purple-colored) and make it always active, unless you want to manually enable it. In order to do that, keep it redstone-powered and place a lever.

In 1.8.9 or below, place a comparator clock like this:

[image: comparator clock example]

*Credits to [Martin1704] on the Minecraft Forums for the image.[2](http://www.minecraftforum.net/members/Martin1704)*

Finally, type in this command:

```
/execute @a[r=5] ~ ~ ~ /setblock x y z minecraft:stone
```

Replace "x y z" with the coordinates.

Comment: but I try that all the diamond block do it

Comment: @AugustoGames I'm confused.